# JavaScript/Google Maps - Draw a path using multiple lat,long

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am tracking drivers by the end of the trip an array containing all the coordinates (lat, long) routes taken is generated. Using that array of lat, long coords I want to draw a path using Google Maps, more specifically its [directionService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). So far, I didn't succeed as the way I found is to use waypoints, but way points are by default limited to 15; however, I have much more than that.

I am looking for a way on how to draw that path using multiple coords, there exists several apps doing it, such as UBER, Lyft, etc...

Here is the array of coords:

```
[35.77204705542798,-5.815865197320899,35.77205120747819,-5.815754188240848,35.77197468036722,-5.815810097181759,35.77201185726312,-5.816182008817898,35.77188028308802,-5.816782866625928,35.77144809183601,-5.817054836919457,35.77130127311978,-5.817231221149015,35.77121654704168,-5.817323279458099,35.77197602552531,-5.818491135420929,35.77211527443405,-5.818831898394636,35.77220613582161,-5.819054426882189,35.77225761824354,-5.819182167400329,35.77557809840525,-5.819685065789988,35.77522352494348,-5.821346612263469,35.77815743782872,-5.822735160242799,35.77863231735067,-5.822959942846667,35.77915215012052,-5.823206036666789,35.77917987363854,-5.82321907562955,35.77913908191616,-5.825751400638378,35.77947725976961,-5.826044519616627,35.77923063670355,-5.82893344672563,35.77920722271806,-5.829544463218058,35.77924325929096,-5.82965650991142,35.77913169320556,-5.830906964998152,35.77917349450947,-5.830173084585434,35.78563643141488,-5.829373128632887,35.7859055726137,-5.829317961099034,35.78659089504106,-5.829249272155759,35.78704770052305,-5.829163948962961,35.78696081760869,-5.829114610331397,35.78687737614365,-5.829067226012621,35.78679073445069,-5.829018024365507,35.78661289235281,-5.828929232334034,35.78652027010703,-5.828884857172518,35.78643576729606,-5.828844387274908,35.78635159916791,-5.828804167105649,35.7862672257822,-5.828763857888811,35.7872100444153,-5.866787159467321]
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to do is drawing simple line, see this link.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Unlike Direction service, there is no waypoints limitation.